# Placement of validation checks on input for an object

Tags: java, validation, input

I'm probably overthinking this, but I have a program I've written that will do the following for an instance of an Employee object:

```
Check if the input for an employeeID follows the format DDD-L where 

D is a digit 0-9, 
- is a hyphen between digits and the letter.
L is an alphanumeric A-L.
```

currently, how I wrote this is: I call a no-arg constructor for my instance of an Employee object, and later I ask the user to enter the string input.

After I get their input, I call make a while loop running against a method in my instance of Employee:

```
while(employee.isValidInput(input,keyboard) == false){
        System.out.println(employee.printError());

        input = keyboard.nextLine();
        employee.setEmployeeNumber(input);
    }
    System.out.println("Input valid.");
```

The public and private methods for validating exist on the Employee object rather than validation being inside it's own separate object I refer to.

The TLDR is, should my object itself be performing the validation like that, or should I be passing that off to some kind of inputValidation object that contains all the code for validation that I've written into my employee object? Or is this one of those things where either approach would be valid? Let me know if I need to clean up this question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is a style issue. It might depend on you, or your company and even the company you work for in the future - I've had some companies insist on some weird code before and I went with it to earn money lol

I would avoid having this in the Employee object since it's not part of the object's behaviour

Comment: Ya know, I was thinking about that as well. It makes sense. I'll pull that stuff out and place it somewhere else.